# No jobs run on Slurm excluded nodes

Tags: slurm

With our local cluster we are having the following problem with Slurm.
User A sends a lot of jobs that fill the cluster with high priority and wants to leave a few nodes free for user B to use. So that user B can continue to work even though with very reduced resources.

Implementation and issue: User A excludes some nodes and these are indeed empty when he runs. But the jobs of user B still do not start on these nodes even though they are empty! This may be due to the fact that user A jobs have much higher priority than B but still if there are free resources user B jobs should use them.

So maybe excluding nodes is not the way to achieve this on Slurm? How else can we do what we want?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing would be to make sure that backfill is enabled. Check your configuration file for `SchedulerType`, which should be `sched/backfill`.

Then, you should consider either:

- creating a [reservation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/reservations.html) for user B, or
- add the nodes to a separate [partition](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html) to which user B can submit, or
- create a [QOS](https://slurm.schedmd.com/qos.html) for user B with a priority boost and a limit on the resources.

Comment: In case the backfill scheduler is in use, the reason why the user B jobs do not start could be that the backfill scheduler only checks a portion of the queue for jobs to be used in backfilling. If user A has already queued more jobs than the backfill limit, the user B jobs won't be even considered. Hence the solutions provided by @damienfrancois are a better approach than the current one.

Comment: In such cases, you can use the `bf_max_job_user` parameter to limit the number of jobs per user in the backfill queue

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Indeed I checked and the backfill is already on. I will try the bf_max_job_user solution thanks!